# How do I stop my 6 year old cat from pooping outside her litterbox?

Tags: cats

My 6 year old cat and I just moved from Michigan to Arizona and now she won't quit pooping on the dinning room carpet. And now she has started to pee on the carpet too. I'm at my whit's end and I really don't want to re-home her or give her to a shelter in a totally new place. I just don't know what else to do to help her. She's seen a vet and he prescribed an anti-diarrheal (nearly all liquid poo) and probiotics to see if that will help her but other than that, he thinks it's just stress and higher elevation. I need this to stop. Please, if you have any suggestions, please reply.

Comment: You may try keeping a second litter box on dining room carpet.

Answer (score 0):

Some say that cats mark out their territory by leaving their pungent poop/urine where it counts, as they see it. So you could acknowledge kitty's need for this by leaving toys or treats where it counts and talking gently to kitty about things. "Bit too smelly for us..."..."Hey, it's your home too, but..." ..."We love you and..." Give kitty time to settle in, might be a while, like humans need, to relax in a new home. Months, not days, in my case, for example.

I swear our cat gets the gist of what we are saying. Confirm this by watching kitty's eyes and facial expression. Either/or.